# What is the name of this Greek type monument?

Tags: identify-this, greece, lock-screens

I found these monument on the lock screen of Windows 10:

[image]

What is the name of this type of Greek monument?

Comment: FYI, there should be a way to see more information on the image for the day, I think in the upper right of the screen.

Comment: @DavidK I tried it by clicking all over the lock screen but no use.

Comment: This happens to be one of the most famous structures of the Western civilization

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the little "more information" blurbs fail to show up on the welcome screen. Logging in and logging out again will *usually* give you the same image, this time with the info, but not always.

Comment: @DavidK I think it depends on the Windows version. On Windows 10 there's more information but not on Windows 11. At least I noticed it disappeared for me after upgrading

Comment: @littleadv I would dispute that claim. The Parthenon definitely, but the Acropolis of Athens as a whole not as much, and the Parthenon isn’t visible at all in this shot. Also, even if that claim is true, many people in the US (and I suspect the rest of North America) likely would not recognize it anyway unless they’ve actually been to Athens or studied classical history in school.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn they don't study classical history in school in the US? I'm shocked, shocked!.... Well, not that shocked... I remember images of the Acropolis (as the whole complex, not just the Parthenon) since I was a little child.

Comment: @littleadv It gets touched on a _bit_ in some curricula prior to college, but not much, and often it’s more large-scale geopolitical stuff, not fine detail about the geography of specific city states. For example, in seventh grade I learned that Megara, Corinth, Thebes, Sparta, and Athens were major city states in ancient Greece, but not a thing about _where_ they were in Greece (which is ironic, given that this was a _major_ part of why they were such major forces in geopolitics at the time). A lot more time gets spent here on Roman history for some reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick google image search returns *The Acropolis in Athens during sunset, Greece*.

Here's a link to the same image on [Pinterest](https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/the-acropolis-in-athens-during-sunset-greece--758575131007056507/)

Comment: Should probably specify that this means the type is "An Acropolis" and what that means. Now it seems like this answer just names the building which isn't what the OP asked.

Comment: That seems a bit pedantic. Most people would call this *The* Acropolis, meaning the one in Athens. No one will ask: Nice, but *which* Acropolis did you visit? But feel free to add an extra answer

Comment: OP asked specifically "What is the name of this type of Greek monument?". The fact that OP was capable of deducing that the word "Acropolis" in the title referred to the type does not justify incomplete answers (future viewers might not make the same observation).

Comment: @Parrotmaster actually OP asked for "What is the name of this Greek type monument?". Someone else edited it to change it to your question. I agree that wording is a bit awkward but it does mean that OP asks for the name of the monument and not the type

Comment: @Ivo Oof, that's a pretty risky edit. Yeah after seeing that I would assume he meant he wanted the name of this building that looks Greek. In that case you're 100% correct.

Answer (score 13):

Too long to add to in a comment on the accepted answer, which is 100% correct that this is the Acropolis of Athens (source: I’ve been there and actually seen it from that angle), in more detail:

- The shot is looking to the south-east from the north corner of the western end of the Acropolis, likely somewhere between Areopagus Hill (Λόφος Αρείου Πάγου) and the base of the Acropolis.
- It looks like the saturation was turned up a bit on the image as part of post-processing, but otherwise that’s actually about the right color for a picture taken just before sunset in that area.
- The small temple on the right is the Temple of Athena Nike (Ναός Αθηνάς Νίκης).
- The columns and other structure to the left of that are part of the northeastern face of the Propylaea (Προπύλαια), the primary gateway providing access to the Acropolis complex.
- The stone structure in the central foreground is part of the Belué Gate (Πύλη Beulé), which is the outermost gate of the Propylaea.

And, finally, answering the actual question in the title, the temple is an early [Ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_order) temple, and the remaining structure is not so much a monument as the remains of a very fancy gate built in the [Doric order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doric_order)

Answer (score 0):

This type of building is called an "Acropolis", which is defined as the highest point of a city.

In this case it is the one in Athens.